# How can I split a cell into two rows?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

Please see the following picture. I don't know how to create two rows inside a single data cell in Cognos.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert a table with 2 rows and a single column for the Version query item cell. Then you can populate the 2 rows with appropriate fields from Data Source.

Please find below screen shot where I inserted a table and populated fields in the 2 rows. 
This report has been tested and runs fine.

[image: Table as a List Column]

Comment: You should add, that you have to unlock the table cells? Anyway, +1

Comment: Thanks.I also found I can unlock table cells and add block to the column, two block appears two lines.